# Constraint not followed on iPhone Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, constraints, autolayout

I have a vertical space constraint that specifies a space of 20 from the navigation bar as shown on the Attributes Inspector, but my label is still hidden under the navigation bar on the iPhone Simulator. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[image: Constraint not followed on iPhone Simulator]

Comment: i think u can increase the top distance a bit more.. Or try uncheck  use Auto Layout

Comment: Thanks, that'd be a way to solve it, but I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: your navigation bar is sliding down, from its original position, check layout options.